# Why cant i iterate through a list in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the headers of wikipedia pages as an exercise, and i want to be able to distinguish between headers with "h2" and "h3" tags.

Therefore i wrote this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver                  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys                                             #For being able to input key presses
import time                                                                                 #Useful for if your browser is faster than your code
PATH = r"C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"                            #Location of the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")                                #Open website in Chrome
print(driver.title)                                                                         #Print title of the website to console

h1Header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1")                                            #Find the first heading in the article

h2HeaderTexts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2")                                          #List of all other major headers in the article

h3HeaderTexts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")                                          #List of all minor headers in the article


for items in h2HeaderTexts:
    scor = items.find_element_by_class_name("mw-headline")



driver.quit()
```

However, this does not work and the program does not terminate.
Anybody have a solution for this?

The problem here lies in the for loop! Apparently i can not scrape any elements by class name (or anything else) from the elements in h2HeaderTexts, although this should be possible.

Comment: I suggest debugging your code by adding some `print()` statements. What is the contents of `h2HeaderTexts`? Is it an empty list? If so, then the problem is with `h2HeaderTexts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2")` not the loop as you assume. The next step is to configure the `driver` to open the browser window so you can see what it is actually scraping. Maybe the page hasn't fully loaded before you try to get the `<h2>` elements. Or maybe the page doesn't have any `<h2>` elements. Or there might be some other reason entirely.

Comment: Given the error message that you posted as an answer, the program DOES terminate... it terminates with an exception message. The problem is, as cruisepandey pointed out, that the first h2 (stored in `h2HeaderTexts`) doesn't have a descendant element that contains the class "mw-headline" so it throws `NoSuchElementException`. Rather than hitting the page twice, once for H2s and another for descendants with the class "mw-headline", use the CSS selector `h2 .mw-headline`. In one pass, you will get all the elements you are looking for.

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the exception message that you posted as an answer and clarify the question since it does actually terminate with the exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter in xpath iteself :

```
PATH = r"C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"                            #Location of the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")                                #Open website in Chrome
print(driver.title)      

for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h2/span[@class='mw-headline']"):
    print(item.text)
```

this should give you, `h2` heading with class `mw-headline` elements.

**output :**

```
Informelle Beschreibung
Der Algorithmus
Implementierung
Optimierungen
Vergleich von Minimax und AlphaBeta
Geschichte
Literatur
Weblinks
Fußnoten

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Update 1 :**

The reason why your loop is still running and program does not terminate, is cause if you look the page HTML source, and the first `h2` tag, that `h2` tag does not have a `child span` with `mw-headline`, so selenium is trying to locate the element which is not there in HTML DOM. also you are using `find_elements` which return a list of web elements if found, if not return an empty list, is the reason you do not see exception as well.

[image]

Comment: Hey this seems to be a nice workaround. Thanks you! Although i would still like to know why my version didnt work... :(

Comment: @JuicySamurai : Check out the updated 1 code above in my answer, should clarify why your version did not work .

Comment: When Selenium tries to locate an element that isn't there, it throws an exception. That wouldn't explain why the program never stops.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait until elements appearing on the page before accessing them.
Also, there are several elements with `h1` tag name too there.
To search for elements inside element you should use xpath starting with a dot. Otherwise this will search for the first match on the entire page.
The first `h2` element on that page has no element with class name `mw-headline` inside it. So, you should handle this issue too.

```
from selenium import webdriver                  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC                                          #For being able to input key presses
import time                                                                                 #Useful for if your browser is faster than your code
PATH = r"C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"                            #Location of the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


driver.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Beta-Suche")                                #Open website in Chrome
print(driver.title)                                                                         #Print title of the website to console

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1")))

h1Headers = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h1")                                            #Find the first heading in the article

h2HeaderTexts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h2")                                          #List of all other major headers in the article

h3HeaderTexts = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")                                          #List of all minor headers in the article


for items in h2HeaderTexts:
    scor = items.find_elements_by_xpath(".//span[@class='mw-headline']")
    if scor:
        #do what you need with scor[0] element



driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that also didnt help me. the problem lies in "items.find_element_by_class_name("mw-headline")". Somehow that doesnt work. I will post my error code, as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're version does not finish executing because selenium will drop the process if it could not locate an element.

Devs do not like to use try/catch but i personnaly have not found a better way to work around. If you do :

```
for items in h2HeaderTexts:
    try:
        scor = items.find_element_by_class_name('mw-headline').text
        print(scor)
    except: 
        print('nothing found')
```

You will notice that it will execute till the end and you have a result.

Comment: Selenium doesn't "drop the process" if it can't find an element. It throws an exception.